# Blue Imp, Multiple Uploads, one at a time, with custom inputs sends array of ALL inputs?

Tags: php, blueimp

I'm basing our upload page on the *nicely* done BlueImp demo, and have had little trouble along the way trying to understand all the inner workings sufficiently. I'm trying to allow the user to add multiple files, but have them upload only one at a time.  I've successfully done that with `sequentialUploads:true` in the options.

Additionally, I've used the include JS Template script to include additional fields with the upload, and that works as expected, *EXCEPT*, that with each SINGLE sequential upload, the $_FILES array only has a single element (with 0 as the index), but the entire array of these custom values is included (indices 0-9).  With this happening, I can't determine the Program ID and Title for the file that has just completed uploading.

How do I limit the submitted ($_POST) data to match the single file uploaded?

**UploadHandler.php**

```
$_POST (
    [program_id] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            ...
            [9] => 10
    )
    [title] => Array  (
            [0] => Program 1
            ...
            [9] => Program 10
        )
)
$_FILES (
    [files] => Array (
            [name] => Array ( [0] => 109_0158.MP4 )
            [type] => Array ( [0] => video/mp4)
            [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\uploads\tmp\php6AEE.tmp )
            [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 )
            [size] => Array ( [0] => 204109399 )
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `blueimp` but `$last_id = end($_POST['program_id']);` maybe.

Comment: Thanks but, in the case of 10 sequential uploads, that would only be correct on the last one.  I'm trying to figure out how, if it's the 4th file being uploaded, how to know to use `program_id[3]`

Comment: So the post is always indexes 0-9 even if you are uploading the first file of many?

Comment: Precisely......

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading the docs TOP to BOTTOM, and *swear* this wasn't there until moments ago!! (yeah, right):

Per the [docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data), the data has be bound!

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
    if (inputs.filter(function () {
            return !this.value && $(this).prop('required');
        }).first().focus().length) {
        data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        return false;
    }
    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
});
```